# not able to save 2 files from 1 form in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have a form that requires a user to upload 2 files, **file-upload** & **imgupload**. I am trying to save the entire form through ajax.

Form and ajax code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="data">
  <input type="file" id="file-upload" class="file-upload" name="file-upload" >
  <input type="file" id="imgupload" class="imgupload" name="imgupload"  >

  <button type="submit" id="save" class="save-icon-btn">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/Save.png">
  </button>
</form>

$("#save").click(function()
  {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#data')[0]);
    jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "comp/wfc",
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
          {
            console.log(res);
            alert(res);
          }
      });
  });
```

Controller code

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/file/.';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file-upload')) 
  {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     print_r($error);
  }
else
  {
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    echo $res = $data['file_name'];
  }


$config2['upload_path'] = './assets/img/.';
$config2['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|txt';
$config2['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config2['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config2);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('imgupload')) 
  {
    $error1 = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    print_r($error1);
  }
else
  {
    $data1 = $this->upload->data();
    echo $res1 = $data1['file_name'];
  }
```

The issus is that in the controller code only 1 of the files get uploaded. If i keep file-upload as the first upload code then only this will get uploaded and imgupload will not get uploaded.

And if i keep imgupload as the first upload code then only this will get uploaded and file-upload will not get uploaded.

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Can anyone please tell a solution to this problem

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya it is given in ajax part

Comment: your ajax is ok but from backend you must use foreach for upload multiple files

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya won't foreach be used in a scenario where there is multiple upload from single upload input.

Comment: i don't see any multiple attribute on your input filed

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya yes because i want single upload on a single input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this updated function. You were doing some strange things e.g. initializing the first and not the second. As CI is a singleton, this could result in some issues (not saying that this was the root cause).

```
        $this->load->library('upload');

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_FILES);

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/file/.';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file-upload')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);
        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            echo $res = $data['file_name'];
        }

        $config2['upload_path'] = './assets/img/.';
        $config2['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|txt';
        $config2['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
        $config2['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->upload->initialize($config2, true);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('imgupload')) {
            $error1 = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error1);
        } else {
            $data1 = $this->upload->data();
            echo $res1 = $data1['file_name'];
        }
```

If it doesn't work. Please let us know what the `$_FILES` array is printing.

UPDATE:

It wasn't working because `$this->load->library('upload', $config2);`. When CI sees load it checks first if the class is loaded regardless of the parameters being passed, as it was already loaded this line was ignored and the settings from `$config` (the first image upload) were being used.

Comment: Thanks alot. Its a huge help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

JS Code

```
$("#save").click(function()
  {
    var formData = new FormData();

    $f1 = $('#file-upload');
    $f2 = $('#imgupload');

    formData.append('file-upload', $f1.get(0).files[0]);
    formData.append('imgupload', $f2.get(0).files[0]);

    jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "comp/wfc",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
          {
            console.log(res);
            alert(res);
          }
      });
  });
```

FYI, You can try below too if you are not aware of

Instead of multiple file input try to the single file input with **multiple = "multiple"**

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file-upload" class="file-upload" name="file-upload" >
```

Comment: tried your way, but only 1 file is getting uploaded

Comment: Can you please check the network tab in console once for Ajax call. See how many files submitted.

Comment: It seems that whatever code i place first in controller only that file is getting uploaded and for the 2nd part of the code it says that the file is not selected

Comment: Try to use var_dump($_FILES);die(); to view the uploaded files.

Comment: only  file-upload is getting uploaded

Comment: I have tried this code in jsfiddle. It is uploading two files.

Comment: Try the same code without AJAX and see the files upload.

Comment: can you please share the fiddle

Comment: the o/p is coming like this: array(2) {
  ["file-upload"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "abc.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php5584.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(7139)
  }

Comment: I was not able to check the if the file is getting uploaded of not

Comment: check the network tab in browser console. Open console before clicking the submit button

Comment: yeah it is working in fiddle but in my code it is not getting displayed for some reason which i am not able to understand

Comment: Thought I should mention, I've been able to get both files via `print_r($_FILES)` using your original method. I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but perhaps add an `e.preventDefault()` and `.click(function(e) {`