# not able to upload file in codeigniter form

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have a form that allows the use to enter data and upload files

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <input type="file" id="fileImage" class="fileImage" name="fileImage" >
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="save-icon-btn">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Ajax Code

```
$("#save").click(function()
  {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
    jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "class/student",
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
          {
            console.log(res);
            alert(res);
          }
      });
  });
```

Backend Code

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/student/.';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileImage')) 
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       print_r($error);
    }
else
    {
      $data = $this->upload->data();
    }
```

I wish to add one more upload feature that allows the user to upload one more file for seperate category but within the same form. So the new form should be

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <input type="file" id="fileImage" class="fileImage" name="fileImage" >
  <input type="file" id="fileReport" class="fileReport" name="fileReport"  >
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="save-icon-btn">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

For backend i added the following code to the existing code

```
$config1['upload_path'] = './assets/report/.';
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
$config1['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config1['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config1);
$this->upload->initialize($config1);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileReport')) 
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       print_r($error);
    }
else
    {
      $data = $this->upload->data();
    }
```

However i am not able to understand how i need to change my ajax code so that it can send data.

With the updated code of form and backend i am not able to save both files. only the fileImage is getting uploaded and not the fileReport.

Comment: what problem you are facing??

Comment: @Vishnu Bhadoriya when i use the new form and use the backend code twice along with the change in names, then only 1 image gets uplaoded

Comment: you are only sending and processing 1 file. you have to send both the files and process them separately as codeigniter upload library only does one at a time. you have the logic correct, you just need to duplicate it (essentially).

Comment: Also is this your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186671/not-able-to-save-2-files-from-1-form-in-codeigniter ... you really shouldnt repeat questions

Comment: @Alex I have updated the post, and the link you have given is not mine, but yes i am following it as it is the same situation as mine

Answer (score 0):

ajax code :

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
form_data.append('my_file3[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
form_data.append('my_file3[]', $('input[type=file]')[1].files[0]); 
jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "class/student",
        data: form_data,
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
          {
            console.log(res);
            alert(res);
          }
      });
```

in controller following code:

```
 $cpt = count ($_FILES['my_file3']['name']);
    $target_dir = 'assets/files';
    $this->common_lib->make_dir_if_not($target_dir);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i ++) {

        $_FILES['images']['name'] = $_FILES['my_file3']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['type'] = $_FILES['my_file3']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['my_file3']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['error'] = $_FILES['my_file3']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['size'] = $_FILES['my_file3']['size'][$i];

        $config = $this->common_lib->set_upload_config($target_dir);

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config); 
        if($this->upload->do_upload("images")){
        $fileName = $_FILES['images']['name'];
        $images[] = $fileName;
        $my_file .= $fileName;
        }
    }
```

** i made common library(common_lib) for common function like mail settings,upload settungs,make directory,etc. you can use your custom config.

Comment: added your given parameters but only 1 file is getting uploaded

Comment: The way you have the code written, you may only upload 1 file at a time

Comment: You should explain what this means and how it is expected to solve the problem.

Comment: @ezw can you please have a look at the updated post

Comment: @sorak I have updated the post can you please have a look at it

Comment: updated the code now. checked on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. I will elaborate on it if it works.

```
print_r($_FILES); // show me this if it doesn't work

$this->load->library('upload');

$config['upload_path'] = './assets/student/.';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileImage')) 
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       print_r($error);
    }
else
    {
      $data = $this->upload->data();
    }

$config1['upload_path'] = './assets/report/.';
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
$config1['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;
$config1['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->upload->initialize($config1, true);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fileReport')) 
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       print_r($error);
    }
else
    {
      $data = $this->upload->data();
    }
```